# Show $\textrm{Tr}(f\circ f^*)\ge 0$ for euclidian/hermitian space $(V,<,>)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

How can I show that for an euclidian/hermitian space $(V,<,>)$, for every endomorphism $f:V\to V$ and the adjoint map $f^*$ the inequality $\textrm{Tr}(f\circ f^*)\ge 0$ is valid and only when $f=0$ it is an equality?

Comment: If $V$ is finite dimensional and you write $f$ as a matrix, $Tr(A^*A)=\sum |a_{ij}|^2$.

Comment: @Aaron $V$ indeed is finite dimensional!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a computation as a comment, but here is a more conceptual answer. Let $v$ be an eigenvector for $f^*f$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then 
$$\lambda <v,v>=<v,f^*fv>=<fv,fv>\geq 0$$

With equality if and only if $fv =0$. Since trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, this must be non-negative.

What if all the eigenvalues are zero?  If we knew we had a basis of eigenvectors we would be done. If we don't want to quote the spectral theorem, there is a little bit of work to do. I leave it as an exercise to the interested reader.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is the same in the hermitian case, isn't it?

Comment: I was doing the hermetian case. If you want to be able to do what I did in the Euclidean case you need to know your eigenvalues are real to begin with (spectral theorem), or you need to extend your metric to a hermetian one.